# uninitialized constant ActiveStorage::Identification::Net

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have ActiveStorage set up on a new project and it's successfully saving the files that are selected in development, but when they are submitted, I get this error on the update action:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveStorage::Identification::Net
```

With the offending code in the controller being:

```
@entry.attributes = wiki_params
```

It's set as an instance variable here then I merge in other values, then call `update_attributes` on the whole thing.

My white list looks like:

```
def wiki_params
  params.require(:wiki).permit(:content, :category, :new_category, :title, files: [])
end
```

The files are actually uploading fine and displaying fine afterwards in the view, it's just this line in the update that squawks.

I found this [GH issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/omniauth-azure-activedirectory/issues/33) that is specific to Azure and adds `require "net/http"`. If I require that at the top of the controller it works without complaining.

I'm assuming requiring net/http on the controller is not the expected behavior, but I'm curious why this works and if I have something else set up incorrectly to need this at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like we were missing a require in [this file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/360d9bdbf387f03c0b1ca1911fe1b80781f8cce2/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/identification.rb). I added it [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cfcb92f9eaf78daefe21335bcabf813842c0ab07). The next release candidate for 5.2.0 will include the fix. Sorry!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I was pretty sure it was me who was doing something wrong or I would have opened an issue on GH :)